# Use dropdown selected data Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a drop down containing response data from a axios request

```
<multiselect v-model="order.orderJCname" id="orderJCname" name="orderJCname" :options="orderRCnameoptions" label="nicename"></multiselect>
```

On selection of the record form my response objects i want to then populate three addtional forms elements with extra data from the selected object?

```
 <div class="row">
   <label class="col-sm-12" for="orderACjobtitle">Job Title</label>
       <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input v-model="orderRCnameoptions.job_title" v-bind="orderRCnameoptions.job_title" name="orderACjobtitle" type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="orderACjobtitle"/>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried V-Bind but not sure if im in the right ball park

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'd make use of the [select event](https://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/#sub-events) of vue-multiselect:

```
<multiselect v-model="order.orderJCname" id="orderJCname" name="orderJCname" :options="orderRCnameoptions" label="nicename" @select="onSelect"></multiselect>
```

Then in your vue components you create the according method, which stores the selected value:

```
methods: {
    onSelect(selectedOption, id) {
        this.selectedOption = selectedOption;
    }
}
```

Last part would be the binding to those 3 text boxes you mentioned. All of them should reference the same data field:

```
<input type="text" name="text1" v-model="selectedOption.key1" />
<input type="text" name="text2" v-model="selectedOption.key2" />
<input type="text" name="text3" v-model="selectedOption.key3" />
```

Cheers!

Comment: That looks right but I get the error - Property or method "selectedOption" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Comment: You have to initialize `selectedOption` in your components data attribute.

Comment: So added selectedOption: {}, to the data property and it still gives me the above error

Comment: Have a look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbbkbsj2/ . Unfortunately I can't show you multiselect.